# postgresql - delete duplicate object in json

Tags: postgresql, query, delete

I need to remove duplicated objects in a jsonb field in table in PostgreSQL 12.7.
How can I do this for all rows in table?

In this example I need to remove the 3th and 4th object (date: 2022-09-12)

```
[
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-14",
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-13",
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-12",
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-12",
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-11",
    
  }
]
```

Comment: `unnest` `group by`  `having count(*)=1`

Comment: Can you explain it better? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this perhaps:

```
with a as ( select value::text from json_array_elements('[
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-14"
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-13"
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-12"
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-12"
    
  },
  {
    "price": 153.6106,
    "date": "2022-09-11"
    
  }
]'::json) group by value::text having count(*)=1 ) select array_to_json(array_agg(value::json)) from a; 
      array_to_json       
--------------------------
 [{                      
     "price": 153.6106,  
     "date": "2022-09-13"
                         
   },{                   
     "price": 153.6106,  
     "date": "2022-09-14"
                         
   },{                   
     "price": 153.6106,  
     "date": "2022-09-11"
                         
   }]
(1 row)

Time: 1.010 ms
```